# Yii framework failed to open stream

Tags: php, file, file-upload, frameworks, yii

I am using Yii framework and I want to create user registration page. Everything seems to work fine but when i want to upload user image, I get an error message:

```
include(Self.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Here is my SiteController code:

```
public function actionRegister()
{
    $model=new RegisterForm;

    // uncomment the following code to enable ajax-based validation

    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='register-form')
    {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }

    if(isset($_POST['RegisterForm']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['RegisterForm'];
        if($model->validate())
        {
            $user = new User;
            $user->username = $_POST['RegisterForm']['username'];
            $password = $_POST['RegisterForm']['password'];
            $salt = Security::GenerateSalt(128);
            $user->password = hash('sha512', $password.$salt);
            $user->question = $_POST['RegisterForm']['question'];
            $user->answer = $_POST['RegisterForm']['answer'];
            $user->salt = $salt;
            $user->email = $_POST['RegisterForm']['email'];
            $user->fullname = $_POST['RegisterForm']['fullname'];
            $user->birth = $_POST['RegisterForm']['birth'];
            $user->avatar = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
            $user->avatar->saveAs('/images/users.test.jpg');
            $user->about = $_POST['RegisterForm']['about'];
            $user->signup = date('d/m/y');
            $user->login = date('d/m/y');
            $user->save();
        }
    }
    $this->render('register',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

Here is my RegisterForm model code:

```
<?php
class RegisterForm extends CFormModel
{
[.....]

 public $avatar;

[.....]

    public function rules()
    {
        return array( 

[......]

            array('avatar', 'file', 
                                'types'=>'jpg, gif, png', 
                                'maxSize'=>1024 * 1024 * 2,
                                'tooLarge'=>'The file was larger than 2MB. Please upload a smaller file.',
                                'wrongType'=>'Please upload only images in the format jpg, gif, png',
                                'tooMany'=>'You can upload only 1 avatar',
                        'on'=>'upload'),

[......]

}
```

The view:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'avatar'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::activeFileField($model, 'avatar'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'avatar'); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be a directory permission problem. To be sure if it is, do a

```
chmod 0777 <dir_name>
```

Once you are sure, you can reset the permissions properly.

Comment: no, I found out a simple problem: I am using static functions and I was calling inside a class like this >> self::testFunction(); It seems to be incorrect, so how is the correct form of it?

Comment: lets say the class name is A, then the static function can be called with the class name - 
A::testFunction()

Comment: But if static function is in A and I want to call if from A ? $this->testFunction(); is not working

Comment: from inside the same class, self::staticFunction() should work. Why would that give you a 'failed to open directory' error?

Comment: oh, silly me, I was using Self:staticFunction() not selft:staticFunction I forgot that it was case sensitive